# Delegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi in this code the protocol `RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate` doesn't work, doesn't call the method refreshLibrary in the `WVdALibraryDocumentViewController`. Why?

`WVdADropboxViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

@protocol RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void)refreshLibrary;

@end

@interface WVdADropboxViewController : UIViewController <DBRestClientDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
id <RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate> delegate;
}

//delegate
@property (assign) id <RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate> delegate;
```

WVdADropboxViewController.m:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedFile:(NSString *)destPath
{
NSLog(@"upload complete");
[self.delegate refreshLibrary];
[[self navigationController]  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

WVdALibraryDocumentViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WVdACustomCell.h"
#import "WVdAViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "WVdADropboxViewController.h"


@interface WVdALibraryDocumentViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate>
-(void)refreshLibrary;
```

WVdALibraryDocumentViewController.m:

```
// REFRESH LIBRARY //
-(void)refreshLibrary
{
     NSLog(@"refresh");
     [self getDataArrayDocumentFiles];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need this line

```
{
id <RefreshLibraryDropBoxDelegate> delegate;
}
```

Then, in WVdALibraryDocumentViewController

you need to set in viewDidLoad, or somewhere else

```
WVdADropboxViewController *myCoolController = [WVdADropboxViewController new];
myCoolController.delegate = self;
```

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you for get to set the delegate inside your WVdALibraryDocumentViewController.m.

In your viewDidLoad in WVdALibraryDocumentViewController:

```
wVdADropboxViewController.delegate = self;
```